# How to split string while ignoring portion in parentheses?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that I want to split into an array by using the commas as delimiters.  I do not want the portions of the string that is between parentheses to be split though even if they contain commas.

For example:

```
"bibendum, morbi, non, quam (nec, dui, luctus), rutrum, nulla"
```

Should become:

```
["bibendum", "morbi", "non", "quam (nec, dui, luctus)", "rutrum", "nulla"]
```

But when I use a basic `.split(",")`, it returns:

```
["bibendum", " morbi", " non", " quam (nec", " dui", " luctus)", " rutrum", " nulla"]
```

I need it to return:

```
["bibendum", " morbi", " non", " quam (nec, dui, luctus)", " rutrum", " nulla"]
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: So you want the parenthesis words and the preceding word?

Comment: Looks like you want to split by comma but ignore commas that are inside parentheses.

Comment: You can `.match(/[^,\s]+(\s+\([^)]*\))?/g)`

Comment: @Bergi, you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of focusing on what you do *not want* it's often easier to express as a regular expression what you *want*, and to [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) that with a global regex:

```
var str = "bibendum, morbi, non, quam (nec, dui, luctus), rutrum, nulla";
str.match(/[^,(]+(?:\(.*?\))?/g) // the simple one
str.match(/[^,\s]+(?:\s+\([^)]*\))?/g) // not matching whitespaces
```

Comment: this gives me the following error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[^,]+(?:\(+*?\))?/: Nothing to repeat"

Comment: @TemaniAfif oops, that should've been a `.` not a `+`. Thanks!

Comment: Ok it works. Is there an easy update to make it works with nested parentheses? something like : `non, quam (nec, (dui, (luctus, bbb),aaa)), rutrum, nulla"`. the `quam (nec, (dui, (luctus, bbb),aaa))` should be one value

Comment: @TemaniAfif No. Regular expressions cannot match arbitrarily nested parenthesis. You can do it for a limited level of nesting, but it's not recommended.

Comment: Actually, I only need 2 level of nesting if that make it easier. For the context, I want to match a list of CSS gradients but inside a gradient we can use rgb() or hsl() color so I will have 2 level of nesting at max.

Comment: Then just allow another level of nesting in the `[^)]*`

Answer (score 22):

```
var regex = /,(?![^(]*\)) /;
var str = "bibendum, morbi, non, quam (nec, dui, luctus), rutrum, nulla"; 

var splitString = str.split(regex);
```

Here you go. An explanation of the regex:

```
,     //Match a comma
(?!   //Negative look-ahead. We want to match a comma NOT followed by...
[^(]* //Any number of characters NOT '(', zero or more times
\)    //Followed by the ')' character
)     //Close the lookahead.
```

Comment: Thanks @Orpheus but it is putting a space before array elements > 0.  Is there a fix for that?

Comment: @SultanShakir That's what the expected output in your question is, though. You might want to [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39647555/edit) to remove the spaces

Comment: no look it is doing this:

`["bibendum", " morbi", " non", " quam (nec, dui, luctus)", " rutrum", " nulla"]`

at least in the console

Comment: Edited it to answer the whitespace issue. Added a whitespace to the regex to trim it out.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you all very much!

Comment: What if I want to do a combination of this regex but also with a dot(.) with same conditions ? Is that possible?

Comment: @J.Jesper replace the comma with `(,|\.)` . It matches either a comma, OR a period.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need fancy regular expressions for this.

```
s="bibendum, morbi, non, quam (nec, dui, luctus), rutrum, nulla" 
var current='';
var parenthesis=0;
for(var i=0, l=s.length; i<l; i++){ 
  if(s[i] == '('){ 
    parenthesis++; 
    current=current+'(';
  }else if(s[i]==')' && parenthesis > 0){ 
    parenthesis--;
    current=current+')';
  }else if(s[i] ===',' && parenthesis == 0){
    console.log(current);current=''
  }else{
    current=current+s[i];
  }   
}
if(current !== ''){
  console.log(current);
}
```

Change console.log for an array concatenation or what ever you want.

Comment: You should be able to modify that to cope with `s="bibendum, morbi, non, quam (nec, dui, luctus (a, b (arbitrary, parenthesis, level), c)), rutrum, nulla"` ;)

Comment: I will ;) is just change parenthesis to a number, each opening +1, each closing -1, when its 0 means that we aren't inside any parenthesis

Comment: @Orpheus Nooo! Recursion is the spawn of the spawn of the spawn of the...stack overflow. At least for some languages. However, a check that all opening parentheses were closed would be good.

Comment: @Orpheus ok that it's a javascript code and it's not optimised, it consumes a lot of unnecessary memory. Nothing against recursion, it cost some memory, but in some cases is a good alternative. But why make it recursive ? It would make sense if I need to parse something inside parenthesis, it will be something like if (s[i] == '('){ i=skipUntilCloseParenthesis(s,i)}, and if he is storing in a list/array or whatever, pass it as argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = "bibendum, morbi, non, quam (nec, dui, luctus), rutrum, nulla";
start = start.replace(/ /g,'');
console.log(start);

var front = start.substring(0,start.lastIndexOf('(')).split(',');
var middle = '('+start.substring(start.lastIndexOf('(')+1,start.lastIndexOf(')'))+')';
var end = start.substring(start.lastIndexOf(')')+2,start.length).split(',');
console.log(front)
console.log(middle)
console.log(end)
return front.concat(middle,end);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to have large opaque regular expressions in my code so I used a different solution. It still makes use of regex but I think is somewhat more transparent.

I use a simpler regex to replace any commas within parenthesis with a special string. I then split the string by commas, then within each resulting token I replace the special string with a comma.

```
    splitIgnoreParens(str: string): string[]{
    const SPECIAL_STRING = '$REPLACE_ME';

    // Replaces a comma with the special string
    const replaceComma = s => s.replace(',',SPECIAL_STRING);
    // Vice versa
    const replaceSpecialString = s => s.replace(SPECIAL_STRING,',');

    // Selects any text within parenthesis
    const parenthesisRegex = /\(.*\)/gi;

    // Withing all parenthesis, replace comma with special string.
    const cleanStr = str.replace(parenthesisRegex, replaceComma);
    const tokens = cleanStr.split(',');
    const cleanTokens = tokens.map(replaceSpecialString);

    return cleanTokens;
}
```