# How to split line with nested parameters using c# regex?

Tags: c#

How to split line with nested parameters using c# regex?

'1;2;3' - '1', '2', '3'

'1;(1;2;3);(1;(1;2;3);3)' - '1', '(1;2;3)', '(1;(1;2;3);3)'

number of nested parameters can be any

Comment: C and C# are very different languages. The title speaks of C# while thes question is tagged C. Please fix the inconsistency and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647555/how-to-split-string-while-ignoring-portion-in-parentheses

Comment: Its not really clear to readers what you you expect to get as a result from the input.  The best way of doing it might be to experiment with an editor that supports regex and then convert that to C#'s RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

What about [this regex](https://regexr.com/4uvkf) ?

```
/((\(\d;)*\d(;\d\))*)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the `Regex` solution you seek, but this recursive method will split your nested structure accordingly.

```
static IEnumerable<object> RecursiveSplit(string s)
{
    string num = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '(')
        {
            i++;
            int start = i;
            for (int sub = 1; sub > 0; i++)
            {
                if (s[i] == '(')
                    sub++;
                else if (s[i] == ')')
                    sub--;
            }
            yield return RecursiveSplit(s.Substring(start, i - start - 1));
        }
        else if (s[i] == ';')
        {
            yield return num;
            num = "";
        }
        else
        {
            num += s[i];
        }
    }

    if (num != "")
        yield return num;
}
```