# c# - Split Comma separated String with nested children in brackets

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a nested comma string such as
`a(x,y,z),b,c(n,o,p),d,e,f(t,w)`

Want to split this string in C# such as
`a(x),a(y),a(z),b,c(n),c(o),c(p),d,e,f(t),f(w)`

I tried splitting using combination String.Split & String.SubString. Please let me know f you any solution for this problem.

Comment: *"I tried splitting using combination String.Split & String.SubString."* Please, show us

Comment: Is the string really like `a(x,y,z),b,c(n,o,p),d,e,f(t,w)`? Or is this just a simplification of your real string? If so, what does the real string actually look like?

Comment: @Enigmativity: That duplicate won't yield the result OP wants, basically it's just "step 1" of my answer.

Comment: @Heinzi - It is the crux of the OP's issue.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems get easier if you split them into smaller problems. This is one of them.

- **Step 1**: Split on `,` while ignoring separators in parenthesis (see this related question for a regex-based solution: [How to split string while ignoring portion in parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39647555/87698))

  This will yield `a(x,y,z)`, `b`, `c(n,o,p)`, ...
- **Step 2**: Split the part before and inside the parenthesis (using a regular expression or just String.Split), split the inside part on `,`, loop through it and add the component before the parenthesis.

  This will transform `a(x,y,z)` into `a(x)`, `a(y)`, ...